How to mock environment variable that uses equality operator
Given the following code, I am unable to properly patch the os.environ "USE_THING".
I believe this is because USE_THING is a constant created before the test runs, so I cannot reassign the value. If I define USE_THING within the do_thing method, I can patch it no problem, but I believe the instantiation with the equality operator at the top of the file is preventing me from doing so.
How should I best define USE_THING once in my codebase, to be used by multiple methods, but also allow me to patch the value in various unittests?
# kustomization.yaml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: my-service
    behavior: merge
    literals:
      - USE_THING=True

# thing.py

import os


USE_THING = os.environ.get("USE_THING", "False").upper() == "TRUE"

def do_thing():
    if not USE_THING:
        return
    try:
        doing_the_thing()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)

def do_another_thing():
    if not USE_THING:
        return
    try:
        doing_the_other_thing()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)

# test.py
class TestThing(TestCase):
    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"USE_THING": "True"}, clear=True)
    @mock.patch("thing.do_thing")
    def test_do_thing():
        ...


Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Hi thanks for this comment. After reviewing this, I feel I did provide that. Is there something I should do differently?

Why do you want to patch anything? Just use dependency injection to pass in the configuration to your classes/functions, so that you can test them easily.

I might not know what I don't know. Could you please elaborate so I can understand? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Instead of having your function do_thing use some global state (that USE_THING variable), pass a parameter to your function that changes its behaviour. That way, you can write tests that set that parameter to True or False as needed.

that feels like a code smell, because the code consuming that function shouldn't need to know about global state. The global state should be encapsulated within the specific method dependent upon it.

Good. So write a class that encapsulates that state and exposes methods to do whatever it needs. Pass an instance of that to the things that need to use those methods.

I think that's what I may need to do, thank you!

Don't. Instead, use dependency injection. It looks like you really have two related functions that need to access some state - put that state inside a class and methods that do the operations. Let's look at what this might look like. Naively, you might do
class Stuff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.use_thing = os.environ.get("USE_THING", "False").upper() == "TRUE"

    def do_thing(self):
        if self.use_thing:
            pass

but then the class is still hard to test. Instead, pass the configuration into the constructor so you can vary it for testing:
class Stuff:
    def __init__(self, use_thing):
        self.use_thing = use_thing

    def do_thing(self):
        if self.use_thing:
            pass

A test case would then instantiate a Stuff with the right value:
def test_stuff_things():
   stuff = Stuff(true)

  result = stuff.do_thing()

  # Assert the right thing happened


In the production code is where you'd instantiate Stuff reading from the environment and passing the instance to the classes that need it:
use_thing = os.environ.get("USE_THING", "False").upper() == "TRUE"
stuff = Stuff(use_thing)

foobar = Foobar(stuff) # Foobar needs a Stuff to do its job.

Passing in the things your class needs is known as dependency injection and helps make the classes more easily testable.
